# PHP Loop With Fwrite() and Writing to a File

Tags: php, foreach, fwrite, ord

I already have a loop that prints "mason is spelled m a s o n" to a text file called results.txt.

Now I'm working on getting a loop to print "Decimal representation of m is 109 Binary representation of m is 1101101 Hexadecimal representation of m is 6d Octal representation of m is 155" for each letter in the name. I've figured this part out but I need to make a loop that goes through it for each letter in the name, and then writes the representation to results.txt.

I think I'll need to use a foreach loop similar to the one I used for the first fwrite statement. I cannot figure out how to set it up though. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$name = "mason";
$nameLetterArray = str_split($name);

$results = fopen("results.txt", "w");

$output = " ";

foreach ($nameLetterArray as $nameLetter) {
$output .= $nameLetter." ";
}

fwrite($results, $name." is spelt ".$output);
fclose($results);

//here is what i need the loop to do for each letter in the name and save to 
//.txt file
$format = "Decimal representation of $nameLetterArray[0] is %d";
echo sprintf($format, ord($nameLetterArray[0]));
echo "<br>";
$format = "Binary representation of $nameLetterArray[0] is %b";
echo sprintf($format, ord($nameLetterArray[0]));
echo "<br>";
$format = "Hexadecimal representation of $nameLetterArray[0] is %x";
echo sprintf($format, ord($nameLetterArray[0]));
echo "<br>";
$format = "Octal representation of $nameLetterArray[0] is %o";
echo sprintf($format, ord($nameLetterArray[0]));
echo "<br>";

?>
```

Comment: Do you need your **Decimal representation of ...** to be inside th result.txt file too?

Comment: yes, this is the main problem i am running into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it after the `m a s o n` you can write another loop this way:

```php
<?php
$name = "mason";
$nameLetterArray = str_split($name);

$results = fopen("results.txt", "w");

$output = " ";

foreach ($nameLetterArray as $nameLetter) {
$output .= $nameLetter." ";
}

foreach($nameLetterArray as $nameLetter){

    $format = "Decimal representation of $nameLetter is %d";
    $output.="\n\n".sprintf($format, ord($nameLetter));

    $format = "Binary representation of $nameLetter is %b";
    $output.="\n\n".sprintf($format, ord($nameLetter));

    $format = "Hexadecimal representation of $nameLetter is %x";
    $output.="\n\n".sprintf($format, ord($nameLetter));

    $format = "Octal representation of $nameLetter is %o";
    $output.="\n\n".sprintf($format, ord($nameLetter));

}


//then write the result into the file

fwrite($results, $name." is spelt ".$output);
fclose($results);

//if you want to see the output in the browser replace the \n by <br>
$output=str_replace("\n","<br>",$output);
echo $output;

?>
```

I tried this and it works. please read even comments inside the code